# Why the {} do not work for this command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am not sure about the difference between `{}` and `()`.
In the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "two">file.txt
ARRAY=(one two three)
rc=0
for i in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
    echo "grepping $i "
    #grep "$i" file.txt || (echo "failed grep" && exit 1) <--1
    #grep "$i" file.txt || {rc=$? && echo "failed grep"}  <--2
    grep "$i" file.txt || (rc=$? && echo "failed grep")   <--3
done

exit $rc
```

Command 2 is the only that does not work. But I was expecting that it should work and also that command 1 would not terminate the script as per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822621/how-to-exit-if-a-command-failed)
Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: For the same reason as https://askubuntu.com/a/521943/158442 presumably

Comment: @muru:If I replace (2) with `grep "$i" file.txt || {rc=$? ; echo "failed grep"}` I get `{rc=1: command not found`

Comment: @Jim: See my update, you need a `;` just before closing brace `}`

Comment: @Jim you misunderstood what it says: the last command in the list must be terminated with a semicolon or a newline (also see the manual more carefully: there are spaces after { and before }.

Comment: @muru:With `grep "$i" file.txt || {rc=$? ; echo "failed grep";}` I get `syntax error near unexpected token `}'`.

Comment: @Jim **there are spaces after { and before }**

Comment: @muru:No there are no spaces

Comment: @Jim exactly the point. Read my second comment a few times.

Comment: @muru:I see. This `grep "$i" file.txt || { rc=$? ; echo "failed grep"; }` worked. But why?

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` is a placeholder for compound statements in a colon separate format in `bash` and `()` creates a sub-shell context under which the variable updates are not reflected outside the braces.

You don't even have to mess with the return code `$?` values while using `grep` or any other shell commands. You can directly use their exit code in the if-conditional by suppressing the console output (usually the commands return `0` in case of command success). In `grep` you can do that by enabling the `-q` flag

```
if grep -q "$i" file.txt; then
    printf "grep suceeded\n"
else
    printf "grep failed\n"
fi
```

If you want to store the exit code manually, the idea of using a compound statement is right ( using sub-shell won't work here!). You just need end the compound statement with a `;`

```
grep "$i" file.txt || {rc=$? ; echo "failed grep" ; }
```

Now the exit code is available in `rc` for you to use with. Or more simply you can just use the variable in echo itself

```
grep "$i" file.txt || echo "failed grep with rc: $?"
```

To add to the answer using sub-shells `()`, for storing the variable context is *not* a good practice. The shells are terminated soon after the enclosed commands are finished.

E.g. Using this simple string equality operation below

```
str='foo'; rc=0
[[ $str == *doo* ]] || { rc=$?; echo "string comparison failed" ; }
echo "$rc"
```

will reflect the `rc` value properly, but the same won't work in case of a sub-shell as

```
str='foo'; rc=0
[[ $str == *doo* ]] || ( rc=$?; echo "string comparison failed" )
echo "$rc"
```

will reflect the value to be `0` when it is supposed to return `1` set inside the sub-shell.

---

[Not relevant to the actual question]

You should always quote your array expansions. Not doing so will split your array element containing spaces or other special characters as separate words instead of treating them as one

```
for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
```

Comment: this `grep "$i" file.txt || {rc=$? ; echo "failed grep"; }` gives me `: syntax error near unexpected token `}'`

Comment: @Jim: It is a typo, leave a space after `" ;` and `}`

Comment: This seems very error prone to depend on spaces. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` and most POSIX shells, while `(` and `)` are special token characters in the shell syntax (they're treated specially wherever they appear, including as part of multi-character tokens like `((`, `$(`, `<(`, `$((`, `<#((`...), `{` and `}` are not except when combined with special token characters like in `${`, or are used in the special `{x,y}` or `{x..y}` form.

You'll notice that while `echo )` gives an error, `echo }` does not and outputs `}`, so the `}` in `{echo}` could not possibly close the `{`.

Specifically, `{` and `}` are *keywords* like `while`, `time`, `!`. They can only occur where a command is expected (in a first approximation) and only when a separate word.

`{echo` would be the `{echo` command, not the `{` keyword followed by `echo`. Just like `while[` would be the `while[` command and not the `while` keyword followed by `[`.

You can have `{ echo;}` or `{<file cat;}` where both `{` and `}` are delimited and in command position, but not `{echo}`.

There are some exceptions though. You'll notice that `{(echo test)}` also works even though nothing is usually expected after that closing `)` except redirections, and that `}` is not in command position. Same  for `{ { echo; } }` where the second `}` is not in command position.

`{ echo; ! }` or `{ echo; time }` work in ksh93, but not in `bash` (even though those `}` are in command position.

An exception to that is `zsh` that tries to recognise `{` and `}` as tokens when possible. That is, when in command position and in some limited cases. `{echo}` works there, but `{{echo}}` doesn't for instance (though `{{echo} }` does). `{echo,foo}` is like `{ echo,foo;}` there instead of the `echo foo` of bash/ksh.

`<file {head;head}` works in `zsh` while it doesn't work in other shells.

That's controlled by the `IGNORE_BRACES` and `IGNORE_CLOSE_BRACES` options.